# Database design for One to Many or Many to many for use case?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, spring-data-jpa

I have a requirement where having a four consecutive one to many table layers as follows,

```
    School
SchoolID | SName
-----------------
1        |  HSS1
2        |  HSS2
3        |  HSS3
4        |  HSS4

Class
ClassID  | CName    |  SchoolID
-------------------------------
1        |  Class1 |  1
2        |  Class2 |  1
3        |  Class3 |  3
4        |  Class4 |  3


Student
StudentID  | StName    |  ClassID
-------------------------------
1          | StudC1  |  1
2          | StudC2  |  1
3          | StudC3  |  2
4          | StudC4  |  2

Bench
BenchID    | BName    |  StudentID
-------------------------------
1          | Bench1  |  1
2          | Bench2  |  1
3          | Bench3  |  1
4          | Bench4  |  2
1          | Bench1  |  3
2          | Bench2  |  3
3          | Bench3  |  4
4          | Bench4  |  4
```

Idea is to get the response as this format as json from Database,

```
{
"resources": [
    {
        "SName": "HSS1",
        "ClassList": [
            {
                "CName": [
                    {
                        "CName": "Class1",
                        "StudentList": [
                            {
                                "StName": "StudC1",
                                "BenchList": [
                                    {
                                        "BName": "Bench1"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "BName": "Bench2"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "BName": "Bench3"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "StName": "StudC2",
                                "BenchList": [
                                    {
                                        "BName": "Bench4"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "CName": "Class2",
                        "StudentList": [
                            {
                                "StName": "StudC3"
                            },
                            {
                                "StName": "StudC4"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

My question is,

1. Is it a good practice of having or creating a nested one to many relationship tables in DB the expected results are JSON using java as above?
2. Is there any other simplification method of the approach in table creation yet get the same response as nested?
3. The above structure of tables as source will get merged into same structure of target tables using MERGE/UPSERT. Will that be easy?
4. one to many to many to many relationship change does that help?
5. is it okay to get such json response from database design as is if i design tables such as the same way?

Note: Assume table names are sample names and consider all 4 tables are one to many connected

Need community suggestions for this approach and better solution if any to this design.

Comment: Off-topic for multiple reasons. This is a technical Q&A site for specific issues, not a generalized "evaluate my schema" and suggest improvements. In additiion, every post should be limited to one question. Lastly, you should design your schema to accurately and correct reflect the actual system you are modelling - not to make consuming resultsets "easier" for developers and applications. I have no idea what real-life entity "bench" - that demonstrates how your system model does not easily translate to others without your experience.

Comment: And "target tables" mean what? There is another database / system for which you must translate your information and export it to that schema? Why NOT just use that schema as a starting point?

Comment: @SMor Thanks for your comments, the table names are not real world samples I must had to specify in question itself. But yes these 4 tables are nested one by one. And the same set of table structure is used as the master warehouse table and the above tables would gets synced up to warehouse table structure once per month. Currently am in a situation where weather to design a table and warehouse tables like this with this kind of schema or not? Will that cause any issues I'm future as mentioned in listed questions.